# How to clone ancient hard drive? (Year 1990, has MS DOS)

Tags: hard-drive, clone, ms-dos

I cant see it as a drive in Norton Ghost15. When I go to the "Backup my computer" option, no drive is displayed for the drive I am trying to clone/backup.

But I see the harddrive in the BIOS. I can boot into that harddrive and it loads into MSDOS as expected. I am unsure what my options are to clone it.

Edit: More Details. The entire capacity of the harddrive is atleast 100 megs(I have to check for the exact number). MS DOS 6.22 I believe. IDE 40 wires. I really need to clone this harddrive. I can't start over from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to clone something like that is a bit for bit copy.  Do you have another IDE drive to clone to?

Hook up another drive to clone to and boot to a Linux Live CD (Knoppix is great) and see if it picks up both drives.  Once you're in the Live CD console you can check to see if the drives were both picked up with an `fdisk -l`.

If so, then use something like [dd_rescue](http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/ddrescue/) to clone the drive at that point.

Comment: dd_rescue is awesome, just be sure to quadruple check your command before running :)

Comment: +1. This is pretty much the simplest way of cloning the drive. Just be careful with `dd` :)

Comment: is it built into linux live cd knoppix? http://www.knopper.net/knoppix-mirrors/index-en.html

Comment: Yep, built into all LiveCDs! (lol know when my answer is outclassed)

Answer (score 1):

You might just want to take it out, put it in a caddy, and clone from another computer to see whether the prob is with your disk or your computer. (Caddies are around $10, depending on the type of disk.)

If (unlikely) you don't need the OS, just .bat's and such, you might just want to copy off your files (again from a caddy).

What is it formatted as; FAT, FAT16, FAT32, etc?  What type of drive is it; IDE or SATA?

Try other programs as well (e.g. Clonezilla).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I believe it is FAT16. and IDE. Nothing is wrong with the computer, I just want a backup of the harddrive incase it fails. I didn't think of doing the MSDOS command to copy all the contents to another drive, which I'll try.

Comment: Well, IDE caddies are fairly cheap and easy to set up (no external power apart from USb required).  I assume you have another computer, but in any case FAT16 should be recognised.  I would try other cloning programs if the bootable OS is needed.  (And I would upgrade ^_^ try Ubuntu!)

Comment: any clue on why I can't see the drive in windows? Thanks alot! I'll try everything you recommended

Comment: In Windows?  I thought you couldn't see it in Ghost?

Comment: couldn't see it in either

Comment: Hm....  I have absolutely no idea.  Windows is a strange beast, and might have outgrown FAT16.  (I would ask what version of Windows, but it would be non-constructive.)  Linux can recognise practically anything, so I would just go with an Ubuntu LiveCD (click "try").

Comment: Windows XP      .!@#$

Comment: Yeah... I have no idea why Xp wouldn't see a FAT16 partition, but I'm sure that if you loaded up Knoppix (like jmreicha says) that it would see it.  An Ubuntu CD would do the same thing, by the way.